# What is Body? `from fastapi import Body`

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

In the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-data-types/) and elsewhere I have seen `Body` used but don't know what it is.

Can someone explain what these three options mean?

```py
from fastapi import Body
from pydantic import BaseModel

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    body1: None
    body2: Body(None)
    body3: Body(...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a Pydantic model you don't need to use `Body`.

You could write:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Schema

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    body1: None
    body2: Schema(None)
    body3: Schema(...)
```

`Body` is used only in *path operation* parameters when you need to force FastAPI to understand that the parameter is received in as part of the body (e.g. instead of a query parameter). You only need to use `Body` explicitly when using parameters of "singular" types (of a single value, like `int`, `str`). If you use a Pydantic model, a list or something similar as a type, you don't need to use `Body` explicitly.

You can also use `Body` to add extra metadata if you need to. Like a title, examples, etc.

Read more about it here in the docs: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/

Comment: Thanks. OK, I just tested out a few things....and it seems that Body is the only one of Body/Schema that a path operation which won't yield an error, but it seems for when I have something like Schema in MyModel, that the `schema_json` is identical for when I use Body.

Comment: What is the advantage of using Schema as opposed to Body in my models?  It seems that I can provide the same set of arguments and the docs look the same.

Comment: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/033bc2a6c9aec3a245eb1f1b4fadb2fbb7a514b8/fastapi/params.py#L202-L236

Comment: OK -- seems like the above shows the only difference is the presence of `embed` and `media_type` ... very cool. And those are not necessary or relevant for Pydantic. Thanks!